# recursive function with dynamic treenode

Tags: vb.net, function, recursion, treenode

I have a recursive function wich objective is scann an structure and represent that structure with treenodes.

Inside my function depends the structure I'll have to create another treenode inside my treenode or just create a node.

My problem is that I don't know how to remember my treenode position when I have to call my function again.

```
    If strTop.TextString.ToUpper = "DMN" Then

        gcTreeno.Nodes.Add("Node")

    Else
        Dim perf As New TreeNode
        gcTreeno.Nodes.Add(perf)

    End If
```

if i would like to write next time a node into perf, how i could do it ?

Comment: If you don't want to spend 3 minutes writing a decently formatted question how do expect someone to spend 3 minutes answering your question?

Comment: Why you spend 30s writing dummy text, ¿? borred at home ? no work ¿? .. i'm sorry about you. But it would be better if you waste your time doing other things.

Comment: I spent those 30 seconds because the StackOverflow rules say that I should. When you down vote someone you should say why.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the other functions .. you can pass a Key Value to your node.

like `gcTreeno.Nodes.Add("key", "text")`